# Seeking Hardware to Recreate Nostalgic CRT TV Experience with Custom Channel Cycling

Tags: television

I'm on the hunt for a [software](https://%20I%27m%20on%20the%20hunt%20for%20a%20software%20and%20hardware%20solution%20that%20can%20help%20me%20recreate%20the%20nostalgic%20experience%20of%20using%20a%20CRT%20TV%20from%20the%2090s.%20Specifically,%20I%27m%20looking%20to%20emulate%20the%20ability%20to%20scroll%20through%20channels%20using%20a%20remote%20control,%20but%20in%20this%20case,%20I%27d%20like%20to%20cycle%20through%20my%20own%20collection%20of%20TV%20shows%20from%20the%2080s%20and%2090s.%20%20Currently,%20my%20setup%20involves%20a%20VCR%20connected%20to%20my%20CRT%20TV,%20and%20I%27m%20interested%20in%20configuring%20it%20to%20play%20different%20TV%20shows%20on%20various%20%22channels%22%20continuously,%20without%20requiring%20manual%20intervention.%20Essentially,%20I%20want%20to%20relive%20the%20feeling%20of%20stumbling%20upon%20different%20programs%20while%20flipping%20through%20channels%20on%20an%20old%20CRT%20TV.%20%20I%27m%20looking%20for%20hardware%20suggestions.%20Are%20there%20any%20existing%20solutions%20or%20recommendations%20that%20can%20help%20me%20achieve%20this%20setup?%20Any%20guidance%20or%20pointers%20would%20be%20greatly%20appreciated.%20%20My%20Question%20for%20software%20recommendation:%20%20https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/87964/seeking-software-solution-to-recreate-a-90s-crt-tv-experience-for-my-vintage-tv) and hardware solution that can help me recreate the nostalgic experience of using a CRT TV from the 90s. Specifically, I'm looking to emulate the ability to scroll through channels using a remote control, but in this case, I'd like to cycle through my own collection of TV shows from the 80s and 90s.

Currently, my setup involves a VCR connected to my CRT TV, and I'm interested in configuring it to play different TV shows on various "channels" continuously, without requiring manual intervention. Essentially, I want to relive the feeling of stumbling upon different programs while flipping through channels on an old CRT TV. All content will be my own collection.

I'm looking for hardware suggestions. Are there any existing solutions or recommendations that can help me achieve this setup? Any guidance or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

My Question for software recommendation:
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/87964/seeking-software-solution-to-recreate-a-90s-crt-tv-experience-for-my-vintage-tv

Comment: *Hi Slartibartfast, Can I ask you about your name?* Jokes aside, I think this is a very interesting idea. You are definitely going to need a PC to get this working but you mentioned nothing about that. Do you have a PC already to use with this or is that also something you need recommended?

Comment: Aside from a PC, you're probably going to need a remote that works with the PC through either a USB dongle or an IR receiver (universal TV remotes can work with that). Also some kind of video adapter from a PC video connection into RCA, S-Video, or RG-6 (cable); What video hookups does the CRT have?

Comment: I'm really longing for a way to make it work using just good old coaxial cable, potentially with some intermediary hardware to transmit content from the server. However, as per your last comment, the challenge with using an infrared remote is that the receiver must be in close proximity to the server, whereas the server is located in a different room. I consider this option as a fallback in case our other ideas prove unworkable. The TV has S-Video, Coaxial and RCA connection. Thanks for your help @Romen

Comment: If you really insist on using coax then you'll need an "RF Modulator" that uses something like HDMI as input. It's going to be a very weird adapter that almost nobody sells but maybe something for retro gaming exists to order online.

Comment: That Interesting, let me do some research on this. If this works it would be great.

Comment: It's still not clear if you need a recommendation for a whole PC too, or if you have the PC already.

Comment: I've got a PC and only needed some additional hardware to transmit content to my CRT TV. I've repurposed an older PC as a NAS server, and it should be sufficient for playing standard-definition (SD) content.